# pros and cons for implemeting a global object in Android/Java as singleton or DataClass

Tags: android, singleton, global-variables

There are many questions and answers on how to implement a global variable in Android/Java.

So it seems one can either implement a singleton or use a data class itself with static variables.

I am about to start a larger project and would like to start on the right foot.

I am just not sure which one to use.

Pro singleton/con Data Class

- supposedly "cleaner" way (but I really don't know why)
- ensures that there is really always just one representation
- creates a new instance should the old one be "cleaned away" (whenever this may happen?)

Con singleton/pro Data Class

- not recommendet by some (but did not find convincng reasons)
- ensures that there is only one representation by design
- very easy to access just by writing MyDataClass.x (vs accessing singleton requires getting access to it first somehow)
- no need to pass it as a parameter

**So in summary I tend to use DataClass but I am unsure because I read that this is supposedly not good programming style.**

I like to add

- the data this global object has to hold is quite big, more than 30k strings/keys. And this should not be cleaned at any stage so that when the app return it may crash because of that - as I read in other places eg [Singletons vs. Application Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android) (the 3rd answer)
- it's not a web application, I use only one classloader
- it is multithread but only one thread is actually accessing this data
- one may certainly also use this approach [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables), but isn't an ObjectClass just easier to use and access in this case?
- And checking this http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html, esp under "Persistent Objects", implies that there is no real advantage for on or the other in those cases anyway.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to implement singleton is to use enum.

```
public enum Singleton
{
    INSTANCE;

    public void someMethod()
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

For more details you can read [Effective Java (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

Comment: interesting syntax - how would one access this singleton in another instance object?

Comment: Singleton singleton = Singleton.INSTANCE;
singleton.someMethod();
or
Singleton.INSTANCE.someMethod();

Answer (score 1):

First of all: There's not much difference between a class with public static member variables and a singleton class. A lot of developers prefer the singleton pattern because the code looks more natural and more Java. E.g. `Singleton.Data` looks like a constant access and `Singleton.getData()` looks like you're accessing some kind of static data.

Personally I use the static Application pattern: See [Accessing resources without an Activity or Context reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7532134/920511)

You can use `onCreate` to setup any kind of static data or even other singletons. E.g. I prefer to setup a singleton SQLite database like that and access it then via `App.getDb()`. You can use this pattern to access the application context or resources.

While using static data you should think about memory leeks. I would recommend to take a look at [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) then.